# using iframes within secure pages

Tags: browser

Since iframes no longer work on my site since I secured it. What would be the best way to display external content on an https page. Is there an alternative or is there simply no way around the mixed content rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to display content in iframe, you just need to use `https` protocol when you embed your iframe.

This means of course that the source site you are embedding must support https.

Forgot to add as well, that the site you are embedding, could have some iframe/embed restrictions, like for example Facebook:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```